# Adding carousel to panel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

First program logic:

I have a main panel and there is a list at the left side and another panel at the right side.

When user touches the list item some html appears in right panel. What i need to do is using carousel instead of right panel.

My view

```
   Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {   
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype:'mypanel',

config: {
    ui: 'dark',
    layout: {
        type: 'card'
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Lezzet Dunyasi',    
        },
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            docked: 'left',
            id: 'mylist',
            ui: 'round',                
            pinHeaders: false,
            grouped: true,
            //disableSelection: true,
            width: 331,
            itemTpl: [
                '<img src="{img_url}" width="60" heigh="60"></img><span>{label}</span>'
            ],
            store: 'Menius',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'searchfield',
                    docked: 'top',
                    placeHolder: 'Search...',

                },
            ]
                },
                {
                xtype: 'panel',
                styleHtmlContent:true,
                style: {
                backgroundImage: 'url(resources/img/Landscape.png)',
                backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
                backgroundPosition: 'center'
                },
                id:'mypanel'
                }
            ]
        }

        });
```

As you can see there is a xtype:panel and i tried to modify that code and i did it like this

```
     xtype: 'carousel',

                defaults{
                styleHtmlContent:true,  
                id:'mypanel'},

                items: [
                {
                html : 'Item 1',
                style: 'background-color: #5E99CC'
                },
                {
                html : 'Item 2',
                style: 'background-color: #759E60'
                },
                {
                html : 'Item 3'
                }
            ]
```

Also i use a controller

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MeniuController',{
extend:'Ext.app.Controller',
config:{
    refs:{
        leftMeniu:'mypanel list[id=mylist]',
        myPanel:'mypanel panel[id=mypanel]'
    },
    control:{
        leftMeniu:{
            itemtap:'onItemTap'
        }
    }
},

onItemTap:function(list, index, item, record, e , opts)
{
    var content = '<h2>' + record.get('label') +'</h2>' + record.get('html');
    this.getMyPanel().setHtml( content );
}
```

});

And i modified this part  like this

```
    refs:{
        leftMeniu:'mypanel list[id=mylist]',
        myPanel:'mypanel carousel[id=mypanel]'
```

Although these modifications i can't run my code , what  should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of small issues that I see.  You are missing a colon on defaults:  And I think you want to move that id to one of your carousel elements, right?  With your code, I'm only getting one page with the id defined at that level.  If you move it down you will see three pages.

```
defaults: {
   styleHtmlContent:true,  
   id:'mypanel'  // IN WRONG PLACE?
},
```

[UPDATE]

I got it working so that you can write to any of your carousel panels.  I just created a direct reference to each id in the refs:{} section.  I'm drawing to the second page so drag it into view to see the updates.

Also, I'm adding the model, store, and app.js so that anyone reading this will have a complete working example.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MeniuController', {
    extend:'Ext.app.Controller',
    config:{
        refs:{
            leftMeniu:'mypanel list[id=mylist]',
//            myPanel:'mypanel panel[id=mypanel]'
//            myPanel:'mypanel carousel[id=mypanel]'
            myFirstPanel:'#mypanel1',
            mySecondPanel:'#mypanel2'
        },
        control:{
            leftMeniu:{
                itemtap:'onItemTap'
            }
        }
    },

    onItemTap:function(list, index, item, record, e, opts) {
        var content = '<h2>' + record.get('label') + '</h2>' + record.get('html');
        this.getMySecondPanel().setHtml(content);
        this.getMyFirstPanel().setHtml(content);
    }
});
```

Complete MyPanel View:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype:'mypanel',

    config: {
        ui: 'dark',
        layout: {
            type: 'card'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'Lezzet Dunyasi'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                docked: 'left',
                id: 'mylist',
                ui: 'round',
                pinHeaders: false,
//                grouped: true,
                //disableSelection: true,
                width: 331,
                itemTpl: [
                    '{label}'
                ],
                store: 'Menius',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'searchfield',
                        docked: 'top',
                        placeHolder: 'Search...'

                    }
                ]
            },
//            {
//                xtype: 'panel',
//                styleHtmlContent:true,
//                style: {
//                    backgroundImage: 'url(../images/risk2.png)',
//                    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
//                    backgroundPosition: 'center'
//                },
//                id:'mypanel'
//            }
            {
                xtype: 'carousel',

                defaults: {
                    styleHtmlContent:true
                },

                items: [
                    {
                        html: 'Item 1',
                        style: 'background-color: #5E99CC',
                        id:'mypanel1'

                    },
                    {
                        html: 'Item 2',
                        style: 'background-color: #759E60',
                          id:'mypanel2'
                    },
                    {
                        html: 'Item 3'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: "MyApp",

    views: ['MyPanel'],
    models: ['Meniu'],
    stores: ['Menius'],
    controllers: ['MeniuController'],
    launch: function() {

        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyPanel'));
    }
});
```

Model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Meniu', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: ['img_url', 'label', 'html']
    }
});
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Menius', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

    config: {
        model: 'MyApp.model.Meniu',
        defaultRootProperty: 'items',
        grouper: function(record) {
            return record.get('label')[0];
        },
        root: {
            text: 'foo',
            items: [

                {img_url: 'foo.png', label: 'one', html:'nice', leaf: true},
                {img_url: 'foo.png', label: 'two', html:'carousels', leaf: true}
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i should add carousel part instead of panel at the end of my view ,did i understand you right ?

Also i modified my code according to your response but i got nothing in my browser so i put in senchafiddle , can you please check it and  say what is my fault ?

http://www.senchafiddle.com/#9abi9


Thx for your concerne.

Comment: You can drop in my {carousel} to replace your panel.  Also did you switch to page 2 of the carousel?  You see 3 page dots? I'm writing to it:  this.getMySecondPanel().setHtml(content); ... I just updated my code to include the complete MyPanel view.

Comment: Changed my controller to write to both panels in the carousel so it'll be obvious something is happening to anyone running the code.

Comment: Thx man , it works like a charm , if you live in Ankara,Turkey , i will buy you gift , your help will save me from fail in my course :D